# Select the checkboxes in list's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem right now which I was not able to solve by using the methods I found (http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BgXrz/, http://code.google.com/p/jquery-tree/). Both don't exactly solve my solution, but they kind of gave me an idea of how to do, what I want.

Okay. Here is my problem:

I've got a list (with `ul` and `li`) and within each

```
<li>
    there is a checkbox and some text. E.g.: 
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="this_name" checked/>Description
                Bla: <input type="text" size="8" name="this_arg" value=""/>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Within that (behind the closing `li`) there is a full tree of other arguments with other names and so on, so it creates a tree like

```
<ul>
  <li>A
    <ul>
      <li>AA</li>
      <li>AB
        <ul>
          <li>ABA</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The structure itself should be clear now.

Now I want to use jQuery or Javascript to check all elements in the childrens of some parent. If I mark "A" for example, I want all the nodes to be checked. If I click on "AB", I want "ABA" to be checked and so on...

I don't quite see how I may do that and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your first and second samples do not match. In the first code block `ul` is a child of `li`, in the second it is a child of another `ul`. I presume that the second is a mistake.

Comment: Oh yeah. You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/pqLts/2/

```
<ul>
    <li>Main
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" /> parent 1
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" />sub 1</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" />sub 2
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" />sub sub 2</li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" />sub sub 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" />parent 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").click(function() {
        var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
        $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").attr("checked", checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in your example additional lists actually is not children of "corresponding" checkboxes. They are actually siblings. If you will make it really children, than it is easy enough to select it with, for example, jQuery:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
  $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you really have a set of lists with this structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p><input type="checkbox" /> A</p>
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p><input type="checkbox" /> AA</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p><input type="checkbox" /> AB</p>
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p><input type="checkbox" /> ABA</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

You can do it this way:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this)
        .find('p>input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked')
    .end()
        .next('ul').find('li>p>input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Which is essentially the same as @mgibsonbr's answer.

Note: I have presumed here that you want to include the checkbox at "A" if it is clicked. If there is no checkbox, omit it in the HTML; if you don't want it checked, delete the second and third lines of the click handler.

If your HTML is actually like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><p><input type="checkbox" /> A</p>
        <ul>
            <li><p><input type="checkbox" />AA</p></li>
            <li><p><input type="checkbox" />AB</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><p><input type="checkbox" />ABA</p></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can do it this way:

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('p>input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Here it's necessary to prevent the event on a child `li` from bubbling up and causing all checkboxes to become checked.

Here's a [sample](http://jsbin.com/ayikav) of both possibilities.